# Terraform : How to map option settings with an option name dynamically?

Tags: amazon-web-services, conditional-statements, terraform, amazon-rds, terraform-provider-aws

I am newbee to terraform and trying to add multiple options into db_option_group dynamically.
Using the dynamic block, I can loop thru each option name but that would add the same settings that I would mention in the content section for each option_name.

How would I map one option_name with it's particular option_setting dynamically?

For ex. I am trying to add below options to the option group using variables and not hard code into the module code,

```
# Creating DB Option Group
resource "aws_db_option_group" "db-opt-grp" {
  name                     = var.db_option_group_name
  option_group_description = "DB Option Group managed by Terraform"
  engine_name              = var.db_server_engine_type
  major_engine_version     = var.db_major_engine_version

  option {
    option_name = "Timezone"

    option_settings {
      name  = "TIME_ZONE"
      value = "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }

  option {
    option_name = "SSL"
    vpc_security_group_memberships = [aws_security_group.db-sg.id]

    option_settings {
      name  = "FIPS.SSLFIPS_140"
      value = "FALSE"
    }
    option_settings {
      name  = "SQLNET.CIPHER_SUITE"
      value = "TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384"
    }
    option_settings {
      name  = "SQLNET.SSL_VERSION"
      value = "1.2"
    }
  }
```

Do I need to pass in the option_name & it's settings together in a variable of type map(object)? I am bit lost here.
Can someone help and throw some light?

Does it require a nested Dynamic block inside a dynamic block? If yes, can someone to explain it's implementation and variable declaration?

I tried to loop thru each option_name but the problem is the content sections remains static for each option which is I don't want.

I am expecting, each option should pick it's own setting that I will pass into another variable or something. And this is where I am exactly lost on how to achieve that.

Comment: Please provide complete code and explain why it does not work. Any errors?

Comment: I have updated my post to show my current module code in which option group name and settings are hard coded. I am trying to make these settings dynamic and pass in the values using variables. I am trying to create a dynamic block along with a nested dynamic block but it is not making sense. I doubt if add options to the option group dynamically is really feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a local block

```
locals {
  timezone_option = {
    option_name = "Timezone"
  
    option_settings {
      name  = "TIME_ZONE"
      value = "Europe/Berlin"
    }
  }
}
```

You can now use

```
option {
   local.timezone_option
}
```

in your Terraform configuration to reference this local value anywhere in the code.

Comment: Thank You for your response. This worked but I want to pass option names and there settings from my tfvars variable file. Trying on that but I just can't figure out on how to pass the value for the argument vpc_security_group_memberships. Because this will be know after terraform apply only. I am using community module and don't want to modify it. Any thoughts @charles uneze ??

Comment: Local values act like variables. The difference is that they are ‘less likely unchanging variables.’ Unlike when you create a variable.tf file and then use a tfvars file to ‘frequently’ modify the variable. 


However, if you want to pass the value for the argument vpc_security_group_memberships as a tfvars variable. Then create a variable.tf file and reference the vpc_security_group_membership there. Next, reference it in the local.tf file attribute as var.vpc_security_group_membership  (if you are struggling to understand my answer maybe create a new question)

Comment: I understood your point but now concern is since required security group is not a pre available resource in my case and will get create after terraform apply. So it should be something like vpc_security_group_membership = [module.vpc_sg.id] ... but this is not expected in tfvars.

Comment: Oh! But the code you shared is a resource and not a module `aws_security_group.db-sg.id`

Comment: My bad! Sorry I was trying multiple things so... But even in this case, vpc_security_group_memberships = [aws_security_group.db-sg.id] , my concern seems valid only. What do you suggest if security group is not already created and needs to be passed from tfvars?

Comment: So a security group resource can contain several variables in it. The ingress and egress block alone has `to_port` and `from_port.` I suggest you create a variable block named `vpc_security_group_memberships` with a list type, and it references one, or many security group ID resources. Then pass the variable inside the locals block. In your tfvars file, you can reference the variable `vpc_security_group_memberships` and then assign a list of security group resources to it.